# How to insert text at cursor position of another application on Mac OSX Application (like OSK)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, on-screen-keyboard

I'm trying to create an OSX application which would be a replica of On Screen keyboard. Is it possible to insert some text into the cursor position of another active application? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, just in case: The answer (whatever the details, sorry I don't know them offhand) is a *qualified* yes - as for example that is how assistive software works. *However* under the sandbox, and hence in the App Store, the general answer is most certainly no - typing into another app is potentially a serious security issue. Of course if your application won't be in the sandbox then its restrictions won't matter.

Comment: @CRD what do you mean by sandbox. Do you mean that if i submit the app to appstore it wont work? But as a apple developer i would be able to run this app in my system? Can you please elaborate..Thanks.

Comment: the App Sandbox is a security system which limits what an app can do - what files it can access, whether it can make network connections, etc, etc. All iOS apps are sandboxed, for OS X it is optional. However all apps to be sold in the Mac App Store must be sandboxed. Look up App Sandbox in the Apple docs for the details.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible. Accessibility enables to change content of other applications, but your app can't be sandboxed and thus not available via AppStore.

```
CFTypeRef focusedUI;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(AXUIElementCreateSystemWide(), kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute, &focusedUI);

if (focusedUI) {
    CFTypeRef textValue, textRange;
    // get text content and range
    AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedUI, kAXValueAttribute, &textValue);
    AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedUI, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute, &textRange);

    NSRange range;
    AXValueGetValue(textRange, kAXValueCFRangeType, &range);
    // replace current range with new text
    NSString *newTextValue = [(__bridge NSString *)textValue stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:newText];
    AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(focusedUI, kAXValueAttribute, (__bridge CFStringRef)newTextValue);
    // set cursor to correct position
    range.length = 0;
    range.location += text.length;
    AXValueRef valueRef = AXValueCreate(kAXValueCFRangeType, (const void *)&range);
    AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(focusedUI, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute, valueRef);

    CFRelease(textValue);
    CFRelease(textRange);
    CFRelease(focusedUI);
}
```

This code does not check for errors and makes assumption that focused element is text area.

Comment: This way doesn't work on web based app :(  e.g: Safari, Slack (Electron) or Skype (React-Native)

Comment: i'm ending up here because i've reached the same solution but between the time i paste the next and the time i move the caret, the caret flickers and that makes the UX of my app pretty bad. haven't found any solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but in Applescript you can do something like

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "Stuff here"
end tell
```

So maybe you can try call that within cocoa using `NSApplescript` or using `NSTask` and run

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "Stuff here"'
```

Comment: This won't work on the Mac App Store either, so you'd best clarify this.

Comment: Adding onto the comment above: most people resort to turning off their app sandboxes. According to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693312, Apple won't allow App Store distribution with it turned off. It may be possible to leave the sandbox on if you use your `info.plist`'s `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` array key to grant security exceptions for different apps. I'm not sure though because I haven't tried it.