# How to find global focused fieldEditor for NSTextField / NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

I am trying to access text in active(focused) `NSTextField`/`NSTextView` (global). Is there any accessibility API that returns fieldEditor (not owned by my app)?

So far my idea is to get frontmost application (owns menubar):

```
NSArray<NSRunningApplication *> *runningApplications = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
for (NSRunningApplication *app in runningApplications) {
    if (app.ownsMenuBar) {
        NSLog(@"App that is key front: %@", app);
    }
}
```

As a second step loop through tree of accessibility elements and filter the ones that have `AXTextArea` or `AXTextField`. Once I have these elements I can extract text.

PS: I don't want to listen to global key strokes/events. I need to display a window over textField

Is there any simpler way to get text than the one I have in my mind?

Comment: See [How to insert text at cursor position of another application on Mac OSX Application (like OSK)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272717/how-to-insert-text-at-cursor-position-of-another-application-on-mac-osx-applicat/22042458)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert text at cursor position of another application on Mac OSX Application (like OSK)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272717/how-to-insert-text-at-cursor-position-of-another-application-on-mac-osx-applicat)

Comment: Thanks! Voted for duplicate